# Hardware Acceleration on Web Application Memory Leak

Tags: ios, css, memory-leaks, hardware-acceleration

I have been building web applications using PhoneGap/Cordova and have been working well.

The apps consist of a series of slides, that the user can swipe to get to the next slide. I have been using the idangero swiper to accomplish this.

Once I tried to scale my apps to contain more slides, the apps crash with a memory warning on XCODE. I narrowed it down to the hardware acceleration in CSS3 (below). The **MAX** number of slides I can have without it crashing is 22. Once I add a 23rd, I get the memory warning and crash.

I narrowed it down even further to

```
.swiper-slide {
    background-color: #fff;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  }
```

When I remove the two webkit-transforms from the css below, the app compiles and runs, but there is the white screen blink on the first page, and simple dropdown animation like slideToggle get jittery.

**idangero css**

```
.swiper-container {
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 768px;
    width: 1024px;
    z-index:1;

}

.swiper-slide {
    background-color: #fff;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  }

.swiper-wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition-property:-webkit-transform, left, top;
    -webkit-transition-duration:0s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:ease;

    -moz-transition-property:-moz-transform, left, top;
    -moz-transition-duration:0s;
    -moz-transform:translate3d(0px,0,0);
    -moz-transition-timing-function:ease;

    -o-transition-property:-o-transform, left, top;
    -o-transition-duration:0s;
    -o-transform:translate3d(0px,0,0);
    -o-transition-timing-function:ease;
    -o-transform:translate(0px,0px);

    -ms-transition-property:-ms-transform, left, top;
    -ms-transition-duration:0s;
    -ms-transform:translate3d(0px,0,0);
    -ms-transition-timing-function:ease;

    transition-property:transform, left, top;
    transition-duration:0s;
    transform:translate3d(0px,0,0);
    transition-timing-function:ease;


    transform: translate3d(0%,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0%,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0%,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0%,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1);
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;


}

.swiper-free-mode > .swiper-wrapper {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
.swiper-slide {
    float: left;
}

/* IE10 Windows Phone 8 Fixes */
.swiper-wp8-horizontal {
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
}
.swiper-wp8-vertical {
    -ms-touch-action: pan-x;
}
```

**example html for 2 "slides"**

```
<div class="swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">

                <!-- Home (Page 1) = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = -->
                <div id="home" class="swiper-slide" rel="bkg-home.jpg">
                    <div class="page">
                        <h1>TEXt HErE</h1>   
                        <h3>Header 3</h3>
                    </div><!-- /page -->
                </div><!-- /home -->

                <!-- Page 2 = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =  -->
                <div id="p2" class="swiper-slide" rel="bkg-2.jpg">
                    <div class="page">
                        <div class="menu-trigger"></div>
                        <h1 style="padding-top:17px;">MORE TITLES</h1> 
                        <div class="content">
                            <div id="table-of-contents">
                                <ul>
                                     <li><a href="#p3">Issue Overview </a></li>
                                     <li><a href="#p4">Content1</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="#p6">Content2</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="#p30">Content3</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="#p17">Content4</a></li>
            </ul>
                                </ul>
                            </div><!-- /table-of-contents -->

                        </div><!-- /content -->
                        <div class="header"></div><!-- /header -->
                        <div class="footer"></div><!-- /footer -->
                        <div class="footer-segment"></div><!-- /footer-segment -->
                    </div><!-- /page -->
                </div><!-- /p2 -->
       </div>
</div>
```

So it seems I need that hardware accelerating CSS3 in order for the app to run smoothly but it also seems that it causes the crash. Does anyone have a work around code that will allow my apps to work smoothly but not cause the whole app to crash?

Comment: Having this same issue. Haven't been able to find a quick fix. I am making my app load and remove slides so there is only 3 in memory at a time. ughh

Answer (score 1):

I'd try two different things.

## 1 `will-change`

Supposedly the future of hardware acceleration is the new `will-change` css attribute.

https://dev.opera.com/articles/css-will-change-property/

```
.swiper-slide {
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  /* -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); */
  will-change: transform, top, left;
}
```

## 2 [`transform`s are cheaper than positioning with `top` and `left`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/)

I can't tell where exactly you are using the `transition` on `top` and `left`, but I'd try to replace `top`/`left` with `translateX()`, `translateY()` or `translate()`.

Comment: We actually are building for Safari, so I guess we will have to wait to use will-change. But that is a good thing to know for the future.